# redis cluster K8S connection

Tags: redis, kubernetes, redis-cluster

I'm running a redis-cluster in K8S:

```
kubectl get services -o wide
redis-cluster                              ClusterIP      10.97.31.167     <none>        6379/TCP,16379/TCP   22h   app=redis-cluster
```

When connecting to the cluster IP from the node itself connection is working fine:

```
redis-cli -h 10.97.31.167 -c
10.97.31.167:6379> set some_val 1
-> Redirected to slot [11662] located at 10.244.1.9:6379
OK
```

1. Is there some way I can access the redis server from my local development VM without exposing every single pod as a service?
2. When deploying my application to run inside the cluster itself (later, when in production), I should use the cluster IP too, or should I use the internal IPs of the pods as master IPs of the redis-master servers?

Simple forwarding to the remote machine won't work:

```
devvm:ssh -L 6380:10.97.31.167:6379 -i user.pem admin@k8snode.com
```

On dev VM:

```
root@devvm:~# redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6380 -c
127.0.0.1:6380> set jaheller 1
-> Redirected to slot [11662] located at 10.244.1.9:6379
```

The redis connection is timeouting at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I belive in all scenarios you just need to expose the service using kubernetes Service object of type:

- **Cluster IP** ( in case you are consuming it inside the cluster )
- **NodePort** ( for external access )
- **LoadBalancer** ( in case of public access and if you are on cloud provider)
- NodePort with external loadbalancer ( for public external access if you are on local infrastructure )

Dont need to worry about individual pods. The Service will take care of them.

Docs:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: I was looking for a way without exposing the whole service, isn't there a way I can use to forward the service to my dev vm?

Comment: Ok , but i think that would be anti-pattern of what you are trying to do.

Comment: See first post, updated with informations how I try to remote portforward.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need any port redirection. You have to build an ingress controller upon your cluster though, i.e. [nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)

Then you just set up a single ingress service with exposed access, which will serve a cluster traffic.

Here is an example of Ingress Controller to Access cluster service:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: redis-cluster-ing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: redis-cluster
          servicePort: 6379
```

You may check a step-by-step [instruction](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengsettingupingresscontroller.htm)

Comment: I've tried many options and couldn't make it work. Did you actually manage to make this work? I found other blogs where people got more complex setup but still couldn't resolve Redis giving internal ips once communication is established.